# How to get an associated model via a custom admin action in Django?

Tags: python, django, jinja2

[Part 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28655381/if-jinja-markup-is-in-string-format-how-do-i-use-it-in-django-and-jinja2) of this question asked and answered separately.

I have a `Report` and a `ReportTemplate`.

```
+----+----------+---------------+-------------+
| id |  title   |     data      | template_id |
+----+----------+---------------+-------------+
|  1 | report 1 | {data: [...]} |           1 |
+----+----------+---------------+-------------+

reports table

+----+-----------+---------------+------------+
| id |   title   |    markup     |    css     |
+----+-----------+---------------+------------+
|  1 | template1 | <doctype!>... | body {.... |
+----+-----------+---------------+------------+

templates table
```

A Report belongs to a ReportTemplate. A ReportTemplate has many Report.

I have a custom admin action for Report in `admin.py` called `print_as_pdf`

```
class ReportAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fields = ['commodity', 
    'date',
    'trade_period',
    'quantity_cutoff',
    'data',
    'template',
    'title']

    actions = ['print_as_pdf']

    def print_as_pdf(self, request, queryset):
        return
    print_as_pdf.short_description = 'Generate as pdf'
```

These are models:

```
class ReportTemplate(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    markup = models.TextField(default = 'markup here...')
    styles = models.TextField(default = 'styles here...')

    # __unicode__ on Python 2
    # __str__ on Python 3
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title

class Report(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    commodity = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    date = models.DateTimeField('date traded')
    trade_period = models.CharField(max_length=10, default='open')
    quantity_cutoff = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    printed = models.BooleanField(default=0)
    datetime_email_sent = models.DateTimeField('date email sent', blank=True, null=True)
    data = models.TextField(default = 'data here...')
    template = models.ForeignKey(ReportTemplate)
```

What I want to do is:

1. retrieve the associated ReportTemplate and its `markup` field value
2. put the `data` field value of the Report through the `markup` value in 1 which is written with jinja2 markup
3. use weasyprint and print out the data-filled markup from 2 as pdf

I am stuck at step 1.

Given the parameters `self`, `request`, `queryset`, how do I retrieve the associated ReportTemplate and its `markup` field value?

**UPDATE 1:**

I tried this to test one of the answers given.

```
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

# .... code here ...

def print_as_pdf(self, request, queryset):
        for report in queryset:
            markup = report.template.markup
            logger.debug(markup)
        return
```

**UPDATE 2:**

```
# Logging
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'handlers': {
        'file': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'logging.FileHandler',
            'filename': '/var/virtual/WebApps/virtualenvs/WeasyPrintProject/weasyprint_site/debug.log',
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        'reports.admin': {
            'handlers': ['file'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'propagate': True,
        },
    },
}
```

Wrote this in my settings.py

Generated a debug.log

However, contents of debug.log are empty

UPDATE 3:

needed to explicitly change

```
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
```

to

```
logger = logging.getLogger('reports.admin')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just get the `template` field of your `Report` model:

```
def print_as_pdf(self, request, queryset):
    for report in queryset:
        markup = report.template.markup
        ...
print_as_pdf.short_description = 'Generate as pdf'
```

**UPDATE**: To [use the logger](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/logging/#using-logging) you should add these two lines at the beginning of the source file:

```
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried to log the markup you wrote. but it did not work. Can you take a look at the updated section of my question? it's the last part.

Comment: I cannot find the log file that it got written to.

Comment: Read the https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/logging/#configuring-logging

Comment: I have read it. It's not very beginner friendly. I have updated my question with my latest logging settings.

Comment: Logging settings look fine.  Are you sure that the path do `debug.log` is correct and your django app has a permission to write into it?  Is markup for selected report has any data?

Comment: I realized that I cannot use __name__ inside the Logger definition. I explicitly change to reports.admin then it worked. Thank you.

Comment: I have now moved onto step 2 of my process. Have posted it as a separate question. Would be great if you can provide some insights as well. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28655381/if-jinja-markup-is-in-string-format-how-do-i-use-it-in-django-and-jinja2