# If jinja markup is in string format, how do I use it in django and jinja2?

Tags: python, django, jinja2

[Part 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28654923/how-to-get-an-associated-model-via-a-custom-admin-action-in-django) of this question asked and answered separately.

I have a `Report` and a `ReportTemplate`.

```
+----+----------+---------------+-------------+
| id |  title   |     data      | template_id |
+----+----------+---------------+-------------+
|  1 | report 1 | {data: [...]} |           1 |
+----+----------+---------------+-------------+

reports table

+----+-----------+---------------+------------+
| id |   title   |    markup     |    css     |
+----+-----------+---------------+------------+
|  1 | template1 | <doctype!>... | body {.... |
+----+-----------+---------------+------------+

templates table
```

A Report belongs to a ReportTemplate. A ReportTemplate has many Report.

I have a custom admin action for Report in `admin.py` called `print_as_pdf`

```
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger('reports.admin')

from django.contrib import admin

# Register your models here.
from reports.models import Report, ReportTemplate

class ReportAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fields = ['commodity', 
    'date',
    'trade_period',
    'quantity_cutoff',
    'data',
    'template',
    'title']

    actions = ['print_as_pdf']

def print_as_pdf(self, request, queryset):
    logger.debug('anything')
    for report in queryset:
        markup = report.template.markup
        logger.debug(markup)
    return
print_as_pdf.short_description = 'Generate as pdf'
```

These are models:

```
class ReportTemplate(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    markup = models.TextField(default = 'markup here...')
    styles = models.TextField(default = 'styles here...')

    # __unicode__ on Python 2
    # __str__ on Python 3
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title

class Report(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    commodity = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    date = models.DateTimeField('date traded')
    trade_period = models.CharField(max_length=10, default='open')
    quantity_cutoff = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    printed = models.BooleanField(default=0)
    datetime_email_sent = models.DateTimeField('date email sent', blank=True, null=True)
    data = models.TextField(default = 'data here...')
    template = models.ForeignKey(ReportTemplate)
```

What I want to do is:

1. retrieve the associated ReportTemplate and its `markup` field value
2. put the `data` field value of the Report through the `markup` value in 1 which is written with jinja2 markup
3. use weasyprint and print out the data-filled markup from 2 as pdf

I am stuck at step 2.

Since the markup I have retrieved is in a string format, how do I run it through with the data I have?

Comment: Why are you asking your question in parts (here is [part 1](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28654923/1903116))?

Comment: Reason being there are multiple challenges in my quest to generate flexible reports. Hence I broke it up into smaller questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adjusting from [Jinja 2 documentation](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/api/#jinja2.Template), it could be as simple as

```
>>> template = Template(report.markup)
>>> template.render(report=report)
<html>...
```

If you want to store the output into another variable

```
>>> final_markup = template.render(report=report)
```

provided that your templates expect to get the whole report as the `report`  template parameter.